# Libgdx share image Uri cant send

Tags: java, android, libgdx, uri, share

I have problem with image URI.
I wont load image from "assets" or "res".

This URI is work fine:

```
Uri path =  Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mygdx.game.android/" + R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

but, loading icon.
I cant modify R.java and I can't add here my image.

```
  public static final class drawable {
    public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
}
```

This URI don't work

```
Uri path =  Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mygdx.game.android/res/drawable/object.png");
Uri path =  Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mygdx.game.android/res/drawable/object");
Uri path =  Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mygdx.game.android/assets/object");
```

I send text and image (for gmail app):

```
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
  intent.setType("image/png");
```

manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

How an I make a URI?